# What is the cm-api to remove parcels from host and delete the parcels permanently

Tags: api, cloudera

Cloudera APIs provide a combination of options to Activate and deactivate parcles.

What are the commands to remove parcels from host and remove the parcels permanently from CM host.

```
http://mycm.com:7180/api/v17/clusters/CDH123/parcels/products/kafka/versions/ver_1.2.3/commands/deactivate
```

We want to have some parcels deleted from CM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [startRemovalOfDistribution](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__clusters_-clusterName-_parcels_products_-product-_versions_-version-_commands_startRemovalOfDistribution.html) and [removeDownload](https://cloudera.github.io/cm_api/apidocs/v17/path__clusters_-clusterName-_parcels_products_-product-_versions_-version-_commands_removeDownload.html)